# Can you get __FUNCTION__ from the caller?

Tags: swift, macros, fatal-error

Example:

```
@noreturn func setOnlyPropertyGetterError(__function__: String) {
   fatalError("\(__function__) is set-only")
}

var property: Property {
   get {setOnlyPropertyGetterError(__FUNCTION__)}
   set {//useful work}
}
```

Can we avoid having to pass `__FUNCTION__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
@noreturn func writeOnlyProperty(propertyName: String = __FUNCTION__) {
    fatalError("Property \(propertyName) is write-only")
}

class Foo {
    var blackHole: Int {
        get { writeOnlyProperty() }
        set { print("Consuming value \(newValue)") }
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.blackHole = 1       // Prints "Consuming value 1"
let bar = foo.blackHole // Produces fatal error "Property blackHole is write-only"
```

Comment: Oh, that is weird. Thanks! "read" and "write" aren't accurate in these days of  computed properties, however.